# I got exception "This is an invalid webresource request" once in a while, how to tell which "resource" are they talking about?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, telerik

I wrote code in Global.asax so that everytime there are exception error occurs, it will send the detail to my email. Recently, I got some "This is an invalid webresource request" exception error, and I couldn't tell which "WebResource" (javascript, image file etc) that they are talking about. Is there a way I can extract that from an Exception object?

(I'm using Telerik AJAX)

Comment: do you have the full exception text logged?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to look through the whole big text to find it. Is there anyway to extract the exact "resource" filename that it said is invalid?

Comment: I would have thought that the exception text is exactly the way to determine what resource is not there, or at least enough detail allow further investigation at that point.

Comment: How do I extract the full text from Exception object?

Comment: First thing is to catch the exception and it's stack. This might take you a while if you don't already have that. Once that's done, it should giving you clues where the issue might be occurring.

Comment: It would probably be useful to also log the HttpContext.Current.Request.URL at the same time as logging the Exception.

Comment: I've found this error (or something similar) occurs most frequently under 2 circumstances; firstly when you've updated a page then posted back using an old version. And secondly when the session has timed out before posting back. I always add the exception message, URL and stack trace to the e-mails generated by global.asax and (usually) I can work stuff out from there.